# Cannot boot other ISO's from USB

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 and wanted to try and maybe install
Ubuntu Studio.
I checked without a hard drive, it works I tried with hard drive it won't boot.
I tried with a hard drive that has Windows 10 it boots fine.
Yeah, I can install it on windows hard drive but I use it for gaming because ubuntu does not have a great selection of games so I use ubuntu for work and Windows for gaming.

---

Thx everyone for helping.
So I touched some settings in bios (not sure what settings probably boot order bcs i think i havent saved) to see if there is going to be any changes and there were. I have succesfully erased my hard disk.
Again thx every one for helping out.
I didnt think Ubuntu community is that big.

Comment: So what is the question / problem ? What have you tried and what are the results / errors ?

Comment: @SorenA when I plug in USB with instalation it wont boot into USB ISO but into ubuntu 19.10 that is already installed and it doesnt matter ISO I tried multiple OS but it will work on for example windows 10 btw pc is same that i tested that on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine does not systematically boot on a live USB.
Enter your BIOS (at startup, use the button F2, or F8 or F10, or whatever (depends on your machine. I have an ASUS, for me it's F2).
You can there change the order of boot, by setting your favourite order. Or you can go to the last page, and use the Force boot option, by selecting your live USB.

Comment: I have but still, when I do it it shows GNU grub

Comment: In your BIOS menu, does it show 2 options for your disk? Like [Youd Disk] and [UEFI - Your Disk]? If it is the case, try the second option and keep me informed.

Comment: Yeah i choosed that but when I try to boot DBAN to erase it. Bcs it didnt work i used ubuntu 18.04 to erase hard drive but that is going to take some time

Comment: Btw thx for helping

Comment: My pleasure! Hoped I could really help